# Setting up Android in Titanium using Android ADT Bundle

Tags: android, eclipse, titanium, adt

I am trying to setup android environment for programming using Titanium.I have the Titanium set up and Android ADT Bundle that comes with eclipse.Is there anybody who has manage to set up to give me a guide or a link to where it can help.
Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Here are the guides for installation.](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Installation_and_Configuration)

[Here is the guide specific to android.](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Installing_the_Android_SDK)

Make sure you have confirmed android works on your system and then try titanium, I would create a example eclipse / android project "Hello, World" first.
Generally this is straightforward though.